# Where is the extraNonce in this coinbase transaction here?

Tags: blockchain.info, coinbase-transaction, nonce

https://blockchain.info/tx/c1669dabe1bcadf50c4b712e42da7b3d3152aef53752731b04a4f585dde6f5f2

The coinbase states this:

```
035fd807174d696e656420627920416e74506f6f6c311e205aaed698fabe6d6d4b889c7cba7d6b5f78928c66ca81b377e39cf502340287a9e7545b9f234c7a06040000000000000094010000bb5c0100
(decoded) _�Mined by AntPool1 Z�֘��mmK��|�}k_x��fʁ�w��4���T[�#Lz��\
```

Which part is the actual AntPool address and which part is the extra Nonce, also why does it have decoded?

Parsed it in json and it came out to be:

```
"vin": [
{
  "coinbase": 
 "0362d8070483ddae5a642f4254432e434f4d2ffabe6d6dbd4affe5698eb19c52b5ac94015a2eaecd44f4b274883786f086673ba406c05001000000000000003c0d701e0000cfc79db70100",
  "sequence": 4294967295,
  "n": 0
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which part is the actual AntPool address

The miner's address is not part of the coinbase part of a coinbase transaction.

> and which part is the extra Nonce

There is no standard for putting extranonces in the coinbase transaction. It is really just arbitrary data. You cannot determine what is actually the extra nonce and what is just arbitrary data unless you know what the software that generated the coinbase transaction actually does.

> also why does it have decoded?

Typically miners will put some text in the coinbase part of the coinbase transaction. This text is encoded, and thus must be decoded in order to read it.

Comment: If the miners address is not a part of the coinbase part of the coinbase transaction, then where is it? I read that the extraNonce was appended to the end of the address. I edited the question include sequence, is Sequence the extraNonce? If it is then I would have guessed that the "coinbase:" would be the nTime and the address? Thanks for any help, Andrew

Comment: The coinbase part of a coinbase transaction is part of the inputs. The miners address is part of the outputs. The inputs and outputs of a transaction are completely separate from each other. The sequence number is completely unrelated.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain